# Can't copy Umbrao.sdf from webserver

Tags: database, file, copy, umbraco, move

I have an Umbraco application running on a webserver and I need to move the application to another webserver. The Umbraco application uses an embedded database (SQL CE 4). I can copy all the files in the application except the "Umbraco.sdf" file.

Answer (score 6):

Add file named (if you like you can insert HTML that will be your maintenance page)

`app_offline.html`

After that IIS will release `Umbraco.sdf` and `web.config` copy and delete/rename mentioned file.

Answer (score 5):

As the Umbraco installation will be using the `Umbraco.sdf` database, you need to turn the application into maintenance mode, by adding a `app_offline.htm` to the root of the webserver.
You need to make sure it is a `.htm`-file, i.e. *not* `.html`, cause otherwise it won't work.

Also - make a change in your `web.config` file, to restart the application pool, so that it may notice the change in your site.

Doing so, will release the `Umbraco.sdf` file, and make it possible for you to download it via simple FTP.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and didn't want to stop the site to release the lock on the file, so I did the following:

- RDP onto the server, make a copy of the file in the /app_data directory (call it something like "Umbraco-copy.sdf")
- Download "Umbraco-copy.sdf"
- Rename "Umbraco-copy.sdf" back to "Umbraco.sdf"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this error related to permission. You must login as a root (administrator)!