# Is it possible to convert a sdf umbraco database to Azure SQL?

Tags: database, azure, umbraco, webmatrix, umbraco7

I have a project that uses a local database(SDF) for umbraco which is hosted on azure, I would like to copy the data from that local database to a new one that will be hosted on Azure sql, then I want to update connection string to use that database, is it possible ? Or I will need to redo the website from scratch.

I've tried searching for the answer  but I can't seem to find the answer.
I have downloaded the website using webmatrix, but the database doesn't download with the whole project :/

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121280/cant-copy-umbrao-sdf-from-webserver.  once you have the SQL Compact database downloaded, you should be able to use SQL management studio to script the database tables into Azure SQL, then update the web.config file to point to the new database.

Comment: I did it, then i converted it to SQL, added keys and everything, but when i uploaded it to azure, i got a lot of null refrence erros. I'm doing something wrong ...

Comment: In the end i created a new umbraco project using webmatrix, created a new template site with an sql database and executed the sql query from the old sdf. database in that database, then I migrated it to azure and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i created a new umbraco project using webmatrix, created a new template site with an sql database and executed the sql query from the old sdf. database in that database, then I migrated it to azure with few modifications regarding clustered keys and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you use this exporter you can generate a script of the database:

http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/releases/view/116839

```
ExportSqlCe40.exe "Data Source=Umbraco.sdf;" export.sql sqlite
Initializing....
Generating the tables....
Generating the data....
Generating the indexes....
Sent script to output file(s) : export.sql in 760 ms
```

You must then add an extra line to add an index on the logins table

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX umbracoUserLogins_Index ON umbracoUserLogins (contextID);
```

The issues I had were that the order of the records generated for the umbracoNode table. You must ensure the item with key -1 is inserted first and that it did not mark identity columns which I had to do manually.

Once you have ran this on an azure sql server instance, change your connection string ensuring you update the provider string to System.Data.SqlClient

```
<add name="umbracoDbDSN" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="[azureconnectionstring]" />
```

Comment: For Umbraco 7 there's no need to add any indexes manually, simply doing the export works great if you want to migrate an *SDF* to an Azure SQL database.